# Shopify Account and Shopping Cart Icons missing from header

Tags: html, browser, shopify, liquid

The shopping cart and account icons disappeared after I removed this line {% include search-drawer %}

After undoing and putting the line back I have not been able to see the icons in my header. The thing is when I look at the website on a different browser I am able to see the icons. Seems like an issue with my browser. How does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing my cache fixed the issue.